# Formatting bug when printing web page

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to print a web page via Ctrl-P or right-click print so I can save it as a PDF. Up  until several minutes ago, this was working flawlessly. I have made some minor sizing edits to the grid I am working with on the page and now when I attempt to print, the web page is displaying some formatting glitches on the preview screen.

The problem is shown below. There are various borders missing from the grid and this is carrying over to the PDF when fully saved. Nothing is missing when viewing the page normally.

[image: Glitched web page]

Comment: Can I suggest you undo what you did a few minutes ago... especially easy as I assume you're using source-control as all good programmers do?

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure what you're expecting us to do from a screen shot

Comment: We would need to see the before and after HTML & CSS to diagnose this problem

Comment: All I did was change the height of all textareas within the grid cells to be 1rem larger. I undid the change and it still seems to be glitched

Comment: Yeah sorry I know this was a very vague and silly thing to post. I did find the problem however, so I am going to just answer it myself

Answer (score 0):

I am aware this is a silly question, but for the sake documenting it, I did find out my issue.

My textareas are currently overlapping borders in certain areas of my grid. This appears to cause those grid borders to disappear to show the full textarea.

Below I took a snapshot to show how the textarea's blue line is going over my grid.

[image: Textarea override]

**Solution:** add padding to a bordered `<div>` if a textarea is in it